# Handling NULL Dates in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have a `SSRS` Report. This report have a field called `Actual Date`. Whenever this field is `null`, the report need to show `"N/A".` To handle this, I have done as below.

```
="Report End Date: "= IIF(IsNothing(CSTR(First(Fields!Actual_Max_Date.Value, "dataset1"))), "N/A", CSTR(First(Fields!Actual_Max_Date.Value, "dataset1")))
```

But I always get `False` as Result. anything wrong in the above `expression`? Also is it possible to add custom color to the string `"N/A"`?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead of `IsNothing()`

and

1st part of your expression (`="Report End Date: "=IIF....`)

should be `="Report End Date: " + (IIF....))`

Example (My report parameter is datetime picker):

```
="Report End Date: " + (IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value),"N/A",Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value))
```